# Java Multi-Client Instant Messenger concept help

Tags: java, client, chat

I am try to implement a Java chat program. In this program multiple clients will talk to each other via a server. The server will relay messages from on client to another. It will also provide updates to a buddy list.  Conceptually what would be the best route to take to implement this IM chat. The part I am having trouble with is making the server relay messages from one client to another. Each client should also be able to choose who they want to talk to.Once again the only purpose of the server is to take messages from one client and send it to another client. If one client is connected to the server nothing happens till another client connects. Then both clients begin to communicate to each other.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to be more specific than this. What exactly are you having problems with? Handling the actual network I/O? What data structure to use to store client metadata? Designing the protocol you will use?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to come up with implementing a protocol; check out [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xmpp).  Part of the issue is determining which other user you will be sending the message to.  XMPP helps to solve that issue.  I would suggest that each user that connects to the server would have a thread to handle the connection.  Then you can store all of the threads into a HashMap where the key would be the username.  Then just push messages onto the thread implementation which would send the message(s) to the client.

Comment: So i should store the client server connection in a table or list, but how will one client talk to the other?

Comment: They don't talk to each other directly, they talk to the server and the server keeps track of where messages need to be routed to.  So user A sends a message to the server that says "Send this to user B" then the server sees that user B is connected and sends the message saying "User A says <stuff>".

Comment: @Delanoy: Client A would send an XMPP message to the server; the server would look through it's connected client HashMap (or ArrayList or LinkedList or some container type if you wanted to box one of these) to find Client B.  The server, if successful, would push the new message onto a queue in Client B and send a receipt back to client A.  If not successful the server can send a failure to Client A.  NOTE: When I say the server looks for Client B it is looking for the thread in the server where Client B is connected.

Answer (score 0):

For a basic chat system you will want the following features:

1. A client logs into your server.  This allows you to identify the client and to keep friend lists for each client.
2. A client only ever sends messages to the server.
3. A client only ever receives messages from the server.
4. Each message must identify the following:

   1. The recipient of the message.
   2. The source of the message.
   3. The text of the message.
   4. Maybe; time and date the message was sent.
5. The server will need to track conversations; basically a list of client pairs.
6. If you want to do group chats, then the conversion will be a list of client lists.
7. When a client sends a message to the server, the server should forward it to all other clients that are part of the conversation.
8. You probably want to have the server log all conversations.
9. You will need at least 2 message types; text (i.e. chat) and invite.